# Passing a Panda's rolling aggregation method as a function argumnet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to wrap a group-by-rolling-aggregation sequence within a function, in a manner that would pass the aggregation method itself, like `mean` or `std`, as a function argument, like in the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-13', '2020-09-19', '2021-05-10', '2022-02-01'],

                   'provider': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],

                   'points': [10, 2, 1, 8]})

def provider_rolling_window(df,ind,window_size,agg_method):
    s = df.sort_values(by=['provider','date'], ascending=True)\
                .groupby(['provider'])[ind]\
                .rolling(window_size, min_periods = 1)\
                .agg_method\
                .reset_index(drop=True,level=0)
    return(s)
    
df['moving_avg_3'] =  provider_rolling_window(df,'points',3,mean)
```

However the interpreter doesn't really like this and complains :

```
---> 14 df['moving_avg_3'] =  provider_rolling_window(df,'points',3,mean)

NameError: name 'mean' is not defined
```

Even if I try:

```
f = pd.groupby.rolling.mean
df['moving_avg_3'] =  provider_rolling_window(df,'points',3,f)
```

It still complains:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Is there a proper way to go about this?

This means: is there a way to pass an argument that would result with equivalent functionality as hard coding the method (e.g.: `mean()` / `std()`) in the function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: question clarified

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all you need to pass the existing function, like `np.mean`. Function mean is not defined in the python itself.

The way to do this is to use the function `apply`. So your function would look like this:

```
def provider_rolling_window(df, ind, window_size, agg_method):
    s = df.sort_values(by=['provider','date'], ascending=True)\
                .groupby(['provider'])[ind]\
                .rolling(window_size, min_periods = 1)\
                .apply(agg_method)\
                .reset_index(drop=True,level=0)
    return(s)

df['moving_avg_3'] =  provider_rolling_window(df, 'points', 3, np.mean)
print(df)
```

Comment: great! is the resulting functionality identical ?

Comment: @shai, if you are referring to the functionality of `np.mean` then yes, it is the common implementation of mean in python. It is just implemented in the module `numpy`. The output of the function should be the same as in the other answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, pass your `agg_method` as a string and call `agg` with it::

```
def provider_rolling_window(df,ind,window_size,agg_method):
    s = df.sort_values(by=['provider','date'], ascending=True)\
                .groupby(['provider'])[ind]\
                .rolling(window_size, min_periods = 1)\
                .agg(agg_method)\
                .reset_index(drop=True,level=0)
    return(s)
    
df['moving_avg_3'] =  provider_rolling_window(df,'points',3,'mean')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         date provider  points  moving_avg_3
0  2020-01-13        A      10          10.0
1  2020-09-19        B       2           2.0
2  2021-05-10        A       1           5.5
3  2022-02-01        B       8           5.0
```